# Spring boot testcase is failing due to (ReactiveWebApplicationContext must be an instance of interface ConfigurableWebApplicationContext)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created new spring boot project with version `springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'`.  When I start my application it's running without any errors, where as test case is failing with error

> [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ReactiveWebApplicationContext]
>   must be an instance of interface
>   org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext

This is my gradle dependency for test.

> testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

here is test case

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MarketDataApplication.class)
public class MarketDataApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Am I missing any dependency?

Comment: could you provide your `build.gradle`, all your project dependencies

Comment: The issue was resolved after I replace  compile('org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-web-reactive')
with compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')